# ManyToMany mapping + additional fields in association table

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

ellou'

I have two models `Entry` and `Entrant` which has `ManyToMany` relationship with annotations. While generating the DDL Ebean adds `entry_entrant` table which contains fields for mentioned models' IDs.

In general I need to extend this table, to add fields for ie date of creation of relationship or user who added the relation.

Is that simplified way to do this with annotations, or should I just create two `OneToMany` relationships and add manualy model of `EntryEntrant` association?

Thanks in advance, biesior!

Comment: Really appreciated if there was an example code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem with hibernate. I used the second aproach and created a normal class with fields I needed. Than from the 2 other classes (in your case Entry and Entrant) I created @OneToMany relationship to the third class. To be hones it`s a good way case many to many is create by two one-to-one with agregation table. Here you just creating this manualy